# Using a web browser read system time, display data and write configuration data from a USB Mass storage class

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, mozilla, usb-drive

I've an embedded system which runs firmware and has USB mass storage with size 79kB. So when you plug in the device to any computer(MAC/Windows), it pops as a 79kB flash drive. The firmware creates files which has transaction records. The objective is to display these transactions (tables and simple graphs) to the user. I've narrowed down to a web browser. So the user (with MAC/Windows PC) can plug in the USB device mass storage and open an HTML file in the mass storage drive and view all the transactions in the form of tables and simple bar graphs. The tricky part comes here: the device(firmware) needs to update it's clock, and this time input has to be sourced from the MAC/Windows PC. How can this be achieved?

This is the minimum requirement. Further, through the web browser the user wants to write some configuration parameters for e.g. through a text box and a submit button in the HTML page.
NOTE: Here the device has USB mass storage type and the web browser approach were selected so that there is no prerequisites for the user.

Please suggest an alternative if this can be done using another approach for e.g. a different class of USB or some other application locally available on MAC/Windows desktop/laptop. For e.g. the application should run on both on Mac and Windows i.e. the code should be the same but can be built into separate packages one for Mac and the other (.exe) for Windows. Please suggest a platform for this that has same source but can be built for both mac and windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way a web browser could write to a file. If such a thing was possible, it would be a huge security issue.

You have to write a piece of native software to do all the tasks you name. That can be done in pretty much any programming language, and if you're developing embedded systems I reckon you must have some experience in programming.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. The most important thing being considered was the application should be user friendly. Secondly, if there is a need to write native software then the software should run on both on Mac and Windows i.e. the code should be the same but can be built into separate packages one for Mac and the other (.exe) for Windows. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: This is not really a very platform specific issue, so writing a cross platform application shouldn't be hard. If you want to use the same package on multiple systems and have no preference regarding the programming language, you could write the software in Java and have multiple launchers for multiple systems.

Comment: Of course, you do need to recognize the platform in your code to handle minor platform differences like the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at doing something similar and have an idea, though you may be better equipped to run with it than I am.  Have the define contain a directory called "SET_DATE" with files "YEAR15" through "YEAR99", "MON01" through "MON12", "DATE01" through "DATE31", "H00" through "H23", "M00" through "M59", "S00" through "S59", and "SET"; each such file should start at a different sector, though none of the sectors in question need to contain any data (they need not physically be stored anywhere).  To set the date to July 4, 2020 at 12:34:56pm, read the following files in sequence:

```
SET_DATE/YEAR20
SET_DATE/MONTH07
SET_DATE/DATE04
SET_DATE/H12
SET_DATE/M34
SET_DATE/S56
SET_DATE/SET
```

The last access should cause the unit to set its clock.  If a user might want to set the clock more than once, that could be accommodated by either having a bunch of essentially-identical directories under SET_DATE (so setting the date the first time would use SET_DATE/00/YEAR20, the second time SET_DATE/01/YEAR20, etc.) and/or having the drive unmount/remount itself if necessary to clear out any caching.

I would think it unwise to have directory fetches trigger actions, since Windows or an anti-virus tool might decide to pre-cache all the directories in a drive when it is mounted. I would not expect Windows or a browser to eagerly load files, however, so I would think one could have read accesses trigger actions.